# PHP file not found in webpack localhost

Tags: php, ajax, email

Hi so I have the following js code making call to mail.php

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mail.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $this.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {

        if ( isJSON(data) ) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
        }       
    },
    error: function(){
            // do something
        }
    });
```

When the ajax call is made: in my console it says POST http://localhost:8080/mail.php 404 (Not Found), and a XHR Response says: Cannot POST /mail.php

A similar post which mentions checking if the file in the same directory, it is. When I manually type out the url localhost:8080/mail.php it downloads the file. I have php installed, I am running in webpack-dev and react.

Comment: Please try with full url path not only mail.php .

Comment: mail.php should be in root directory

Comment: its in the root directory, same directory as my index.html

Comment: also my header request url is http://localhost:8080/mail.php so it is the right path, when I go to the url it downloads the php file.